# Android color for Material Design

Tags: android, colors, material-design

I am still a begginer in mobile app development.

I am trying to create a android mobile app and still unable to find a good color combination for the app. When i was search for the color combination / color palette, i found the Material Design Guide by google [here](http://www.google.com/design/spec/style/color.html#color-color-palette). Afterwards, i saw the color guide section. However, i have trouble to find the XML file. Is there anyone have the XML file which containing all of the colors from the Google Material Design ?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

[Here](http://www.google.com/design/spec/style/color.html#color-color-palette) is a complete list of all the material design colors you will ever need. If you're looking for good color combinations for your app, then check out [Material Palette](http://www.materialpalette.com/)

Edit: [Here](https://gist.github.com/daniellevass/b0b8cfa773488e138037) is an XML file containing all(?) of the Material design colors.

Comment: i've already seen the material design from google and tried the Material Pallette, but i need the XML file for those colors because i want to experimenting the colors in my android app. Thank you before

Comment: Thank you so much. that is what i want. But can you tell me what the meaning of A100, A200, A300 in the Material Design colors?

Comment: I think they are used to define different color levels. The 500 colors are primary colors., 700 colors are mostly used in status bars etc. Also, A100, A200 are used as Accent colors as far as I know. You can read all about them in the documentation.

Comment: Well that is nice explanation, i though A is stand for alpha. Thank you before

Answer (score 1):

There is no XML file that contains the material colors by default. You will have to add them manually.

Here are a few you can add to your colors.xml right away:

```
<color name="pink">#e91e63</color>
<color name="purple">#9c27b0</color>
<color name="deepPurple">#673ab7</color>
<color name="indigo">#3f51b5</color>
<color name="blue">#2196f3</color>
<color name="lightBlue">#03a9f4</color>
<color name="cyan">#00bcd4</color>
<color name="teal">#009688</color>
<color name="green">#4caf50</color>
<color name="lightGreen">#8bc34a</color>
<color name="lime">#cddc39</color>
<color name="yellow">#ffeb3b</color>
<color name="amber">#ffc107</color>
<color name="orange">#ff9800</color>
<color name="deepOrange">#ff5722</color>
<color name="brown">#795548</color>
<color name="blueGray">#607d8b</color>
```

A few colors are missing, but you can add these on your own I think ;)

Comment: Thanks for the colors, but i need more because i need to try all the colors from the material design.

Answer (score 1):

You can refer google [material color tool](https://material.io/tools/color/) **website**, which even displays a user interface while selecting colors.

Also, you may download the [HexCode](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.shaheershukur.hexcode) **android application**, if you want the material design handy and offline.